# writeFile no create new file

Tags: node.js

this is the syntax, no errors on terminal , it just doesn't create the file `todos.json` with the [] array

Do you know what the problem is?

```
const express = require( 'express' ); //Web framework
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const app = express();
const initialTodos = [];
const fileName = 'todos.json';
const store = {
  async read() {
    try {
      await fs.access(fileName);
      this.todos = JSON.parse((await fs.readFile(fileName)).toString());
    } catch (e) {
      this.todos = initialTodos;
    }
    return this.todos;
  },

  async save() {
    try {
      await fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(this.todos));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },

  async getIndexById(id) {
    try {
      const todos = await this.read();
      return todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === +id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },

  async getNextTodoId() {
    let maxId = 1;
    const todos = await this.read();
    todos.forEach(todo => {
      if (todo.id > maxId) maxId = todo.id;
    });
    return maxId + 1;
  },
  todos: []
};

app.get('/todos', function (req, res) {
  res.json(store.read);
});

var port = 5000;
app.listen( port, function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

store.read is a promise. try this

```js
app.get('/todos', function (req, res) {
  store.read().then(function (data) {
    res.json(data);
  });
});
```